# Role does not work with (LDAP) Active directory

Tags: ldap, debian, ecm, openkm

I have successfully installed openkmcommunity edition (Version 6.3.6, Tomcat-8.5.24, PostgeSQL 9.4.15 and Debian 8.2.0)  with MS AD (windows 2012 R2) using advanced configuration and best practices in docs :

https://docs.openkm.com/kcenter/view/okm-6.3-com/active-directory-advanced-configuration.html
          https://docs.openkm.com/kcenter/view/okm-6.3-com/ldap-best-practices-for-filtering-users-and-roles.html

But with these docs, I had two problems the user ID was a trigram (sAMAccountName) and the user ID in Role was a First Name and Last Name (CN).
With the option Principal.ldap.users.from.roles on True, I could see openKm creates users with ID First Name and Last Name (CN).

For one user, I had two accounts:

```
ID = MLE Name= Mi** Lenormand  Mail= **            Roles = ROLE_USER ROLE_TEST

ID = Mi** Lenormand   Name=Mi** Lenormand   Mail = (empty)   Roles = (empty)
```

The second account have Roles empty but present in the role (ex: ROLE_USER) when I filter.

I think the problem comes from:

```
principal.ldap.users.by.role.attribute  member
principal.ldap.users.by.role.search.base    OU=IT,OU=CDG,OU=SDA,DC=*,DC=**
principal.ldap.users.by.role.search.filter  (&(objectClass=group)(cn={0}))
```

We can't filter by sAMAccountName because in member there is no sAMAccountName:

https://image.ibb.co/f9MktT/exemple_Forum.png

The second problems is role does not work when I logging with MLE. (in Log, I can't logging with ID = Mi** Lenormand)

After many manipulation I have solve the first problem, I am logging with CN and password. But the second problem is always present.

In administration TAB

```
[code]system.login.lowercase=true
principal.adapter=com.openkm.principal.LdapPrincipalAdapter

principal.ldap.server=ldap://sd01cdg***:389
principal.ldap.security.principal=CN=OpenKm,OU=Compte de Service,OU=SDA,DC=***,DC=***
principal.ldap.security.credentials=*******************

principal.ldap.user.search.base=OU=CDG,OU=SDA,DC=**,DC=**
principal.ldap.user.search.filter=objectclass=person
principal.ldap.user.attribute=CN

principal.ldap.role.search.base=OU=CDG,OU=SDA,DC=**,DC=**
principal.ldap.role.search.filter=(&(objectclass=group)(memberOf=cn=OpenKM_ROLE,ou=cdg,ou=sda,dc=sid,dc=afi))
principal.ldap.role.attribute=cn

principal.ldap.mail.search.base=OU=CDG,OU=SDA,DC=**,DC=**
principal.ldap.mail.search.filter=(&(objectClass=person)(cn={0}))
principal.ldap.mail.attribute=mail

principal.ldap.username.search.base=OU=CDG,OU=SDA,DC=**,DC=**
principal.ldap.username.search.filter=(&(objectClass=person)(cn={0}))
principal.ldap.username.attribute=cn

principal.ldap.users.by.role.search.base=OU=CDG,OU=SDA,DC=**,DC=**
principal.ldap.users.by.role.search.filter=(&(objectClass=group)(cn={0}))
principal.ldap.users.by.role.attribute=member

principal.ldap.users.from.roles=true 

principal.ldap.roles.by.user.search.base=OU=CDG,OU=SDA,DC=**,DC=**
principal.ldap.roles.by.user.search.filter=(&(objectClass=person)(cn={0}))
principal.ldap.roles.by.user.attribute=memberOf

principal.ldap.referral=follow[/code]
```

In [Tomcat-8.5.24]/OpenKM.xml

```
[code]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">


<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
     <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
  </security:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
  <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://sd01cdgdc:389"/>
  <beans:property name="userDn" value="CN=OpenKm,OU=Compte de Service,OU=SDA,DC=***,DC=***"/>
  <beans:property name="password" value="******************"/>
  <beans:property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
     <beans:map>
        <beans:entry>
          <beans:key>
            <beans:value>java.naming.referral</beans:value>
          </beans:key>
          <beans:value>follow</beans:value>
        </beans:entry>
      </beans:map>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
      <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
      <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch"/>
    </beans:bean>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
  <beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
      <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
      <beans:constructor-arg value="OU=IT,OU=CDG,OU=SDA,DC=*****,DC=***"/>
      <beans:property name="groupSearchFilter" value="member={0}"/>
      <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn"/>
      <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
      <beans:property name="convertToUpperCase" value="false" />
     <!-- <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" /> -->
      <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
      <beans:property name="defaultRole" value="ROLE_ADMIN" />
     <!-- <beans:property name="defaultRole" value="ROLE_USER" /> -->
    </beans:bean>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
  <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="OU=CDG,OU=SDA,DC=*****,DC=**" />
  <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
<!--  <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="sAMAccountName={0}" /> -->
  <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="CN={0}" />
  <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

 </beans:beans>
[/code]
```

If I don't use `<beans:property name="defaultRole" value="ROLE_ADMIN" />`, i can't logging in ROLE_ADMIN

Here are the results that make me think that I'm on the right track:

https://image.ibb.co/nuyODT/Forum1.png

https://image.ibb.co/icMAtT/Forum2.png

https://image.ibb.co/kguftT/Forum3.png

https://image.ibb.co/f4p8f8/Forum4.png

Do you have any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This section should be:

The mistake is the value of bean contructor where you should use the base **DC=company,DC=com** and not all the distinguised name until the organization unit.

```
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
<beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
<beans:constructor-arg value="DC=company,DC=com"/>
<beans:property name="groupSearchFilter" value="member={0}"/>
<beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn"/>
<beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
<beans:property name="convertToUpperCase" value="false" />
<beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
</beans:bean>
```